# generate_rewrite_rules (action) vs add_rewrite_rule (function): which one is preferred?

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I see these two methods can be used to create new custom rewrite rule, so under what situation which one is preferred? I suppose they are doing the same thing?

I can either use:

```
add_action( 'generate_rewrite_rules', function( $wp_rewrite ) {
    $wp_rewrite->rules = array( 'xxx' => 'index.php?xxx' ) + $wp_rewrite->rules;
} );
```

or

```
add_rewrite_rule( 'xxx', 'index.php?xxx', 'top' );
```

Answer (score 4):

They are totally differents: [`generate_rewrite_rules`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/generate_rewrite_rules) is an action hook and [`add_rewrite_rule`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule) is a function. That said, use `add_rewrite_rule()` if you want to define custom rewrite rules. Use `generate_rewrite_rules` to perform an action (from codex) "after all rewrite rules have been created".

That doesn't mean that you can not add rewrite rules via `generate_rewrite_rules`, in fact you can, what it means is that any developer will expect all rewrite rules be set at the moment of `generate_rewrite_rules` is triggered:

```
add_action( 'init', function( ) {
    add_rewrite_rule( 'xxx', 'index.php?xxx', 'top' );
} );

add_action( 'generate_rewrite_rules', function( $wp_rewrite ) {
    //All rewrite rules are expected to be set at this moment
    if( isset($wp_rewrite->rules['yyy']) ) {
        //Ooops. The rewrite rule 'yyy' is not set
    }
} );

//using `generate_rewrite_rules` to add some rewrite rule
add_action( 'generate_rewrite_rules', function( $wp_rewrite ) {
    //All rewrite rules are expected to be set at this moment
    $wp_rewrite->rules = array( 'yyy' => 'index.php?yyy' ) + $wp_rewrite->rules;
} );
```

But this will work as expected:

```
add_action( 'init', function( ) {
    add_rewrite_rule( 'xxx', 'index.php?xxx', 'top' );
} );

add_action( 'generate_rewrite_rules', function( $wp_rewrite ) {
    //All rewrite rules are expected to be set at this moment
    if( isset($wp_rewrite->rules['yyy']) ) {
        //Aha!! Now the rewrite rule 'yyy' is correctly set
    }
} );

add_action( 'init', function( ) {
    add_rewrite_rule( 'yyy', 'index.php?yyy', 'top' );
} );
```

Comment: See my original question for example, they are doing the same.

Comment: I've added more explanation. Hope you get the point.